# Extract and add link to URLs in string

Tags: ruby, string, url, replace

I have several strings that have links in them. For instance:

```
var str = "I really love this site: http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

and I need to add a link tag to that so the str will be:

```
I really love this site: <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">http://www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: You could use actionpack like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442143/ruby-linkify-for-urls-in-strings/1442382#1442382

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn URLs and @* into links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571229/turn-urls-and-into-links)

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to use the [URI class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html) to let it do the parsing.  Something along the lines of this:

```
require 'uri'

str = "I really love this site: http://www.stackoverflow.com"
url = str.slice(URI.regexp(['http']))
puts str.gsub( url, '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use URI.extract for this:

```
str = "I really love this site: http://www.stackoverflow.com and also this one: http://www.google.com"

URI.extract(str, ['http', 'https']).each do |uri|
  str = str.gsub( uri, "<a href=\"#{uri}\">#{uri}</a>" )
end

str
```

The above also matches multiple URLs in one string.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, working code :) strips out the http/s prefix in the displayed link also

note you should regex on uri+" " so it catches the links properly... and then you need to add a space at the beginning to catch links at the end that don't have a trailing space...

```
thisString = yourString+" " # add space to catch link at end
URI.extract(thisString, ['http', 'https']).each do |uri|
  linkURL = uri
  if(uri[0..6] == "http://")
    linkURL = uri[7..-1]
  elsif(uri[0..7] == "https://")
    linkURL = uri[8..-1]
  end
  thisString = thisString.gsub( uri+" ", "<a href=\"#{uri.to_s}\">#{linkURL.to_s}</a> " )
end
```